# how to make widget or text dissolve animation in flutter?

Tags: flutter

how to make widget or text dissolve animation in flutter?

I want dissolve animation just like iMessage ink dissolve animation, don't know how to make it or there any lib did dissolve animation?

Comment: Can you include that demo animation?

Answer (score -2):

I managed achieved it by applying snappable widget.

Anyone can using snappable achieve my desired effect.